# Unable to enter telegraf scene using Stage.enter and the variable name

Tags: node.js, telegraf

I am creating a telegram bot using [telegraf](https://github.com/telegraf/telegraf) using [wizards](https://github.com/telegraf/telegraf/blob/develop/docs/examples/wizard-bot.js). I would like to have several wizards in my bot. How can I enter to another scene? I am using the below code and I am getting error `Cannot read property 'enter' of undefined`.

```
const Stage = require("telegraf/stage");
const WizardScene = require("telegraf/scenes/wizard");
const wiz1 = new WizardScene('task1',
    ctx => {...},
    ctx => {...}
);
const wiz2 = new WizardScene('task2',
    ctx => {...},
    ctx => {...}
);
const wiz3 = new WizardScene('task3',
    ctx => {...},
    ctx => {...}
);

const stage =new Stage([wiz1,wiz2,wiz3],{default: 'task1'})
bot.hears('anAction', (ctx) => {Stage.enter('wiz2')}); // this does not work
```

Comment: `Stage([wiz1,wiz2,wiz3])` is this the correct invocation? I'd expect it using the `new` keyword when calling the constructor function `new Stage([wiz1,wiz2,wiz3])`. I don't know and I don't know what documentation to check.

Answer (score 11):

This is a late response, but it may help someone.
You need to register the middleware of the stages **after** `const stage = new Stage ...` and **before** `bot.hears...`

```
bot.use(stage.middleware())
```

And also you can enter the scene with their ids not the name of the variable. So instead of `Stage.enter('wiz2')` use `Stage.enter('task2')` to enter wizard2.

Comment: And you also need to add `bot.use(session());` before `bot.hears()`. Without this line it did not work me

Answer (score 2):

And also make sure that `bot.use(stage.middleware())` should be registred after `bot.use(session());`. Like that:

```
bot.use(session());
bot.use(stage.middleware());
```

Comment: I had a same issue. After changing order, it worked

Comment: Damm, it took me so much time, thanks!